# java.sql.SQLException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized. at the call to a method

Tags: java, sql, sql-update

I have put debugging display statements before and after the call. Both are displayed with the error message in between. 
I get the error at the call to a method

```
boolean updResult = employeeDAO.updateEmployee(emp);
```

The first debugging statement in the called method `updateEmployee(Employee emp)` is display the method name and that is not even displayed!

My guess is byte code generated has the sql query from the called method which is causing the run time error.

Comment: This is the output:     Before calling updateEmployee(emp) updFld:0
java.sql.SQLException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.
After calling updateEmployee(emp) updFld:0

Comment: This is the code:       System.out.println("Before calling updateEmployee(emp) updFld:" + updFld);
   boolean updResult = employeeDAO.updateEmployee(emp);
   System.out.println("After calling updateEmployee(emp) updFld:" + updFld);

Comment: This is the called method:  public boolean updateEmployee(Employee emp)
 {
  System.out.println("In EmployeeDB.java updateEmployee(emp) Before sql");

  String sql = 
   "UPDATE Employees SET " +
    "EmpNo = ?, " +
    "EmpFirstName = ?, " +
    "EmpLastName = ?, " +
    "EmpEmail = ?, " +
    "EmpPhoneNumber = ?, " +
    "EmpAge = ? " +
   "WHERE EmpNo = ?";

Comment: What's the value for your parameter 'emp'?

Comment: Please add these information to the content of the question for better organization.

Comment: I am new so please guide me. I will try my best. I displayed all the values just before the call, by getters of the Employee emp. As I am updating it is exactly has the updated values. I want to show you the actual code I am finding little difficult how I can show it here??